Guarding tests against exit/death
I'm using googletest to test multi-threading code with std::thread. In broken code, it often happens that a std::thread is destroyed before the thread has joined, causing a program termination. Unfortunately, the testing framework does not catch this case and therefore stops execution. The test case is not marked as failed.
For example:
#include <thread>
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

TEST( ThreadDeathTest, death )
{
    std::thread t([] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    });
    // exiting scope destroys thread, causing terminate()
}

Output:
$ctmltest --gtest_filter=ThreadDeathTest.death
Note: Google Test filter = ThreadDeathTest.death
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from ThreadDeathTest
[ RUN      ] ThreadDeathTest.death

$

I've read about death tests, but I don't think this applies to my case: I am expecting no death for all my test cases.
Is there a way to tell googletest to watch out for termination, like it does for death tests?

Technically you could use std::set_terminate(), but you will soon run into the same problem when a segfault occurs. When you run the tests, you should check exit code of the program, if it's different than 0, tests have failed. Most test runners do that by default.

It actually is marked as failed, after running your test try echo $? to see the non-zero exit code of your testcase. Every sane CI environment will check your test exit code and fail the pipeline.

I do get error code 3, but gtest does not continue and does not generate test output, not even for the tests that ran.

Regarding std::set_termine(): good idea, but I'm not sure what my terminate function should look like. The least I would want is google test to cleanly tear down the test environment and write the report file. If possible, I would want it to continue with the other test cases and suites.

Side note: in our company framework, the equivalent code would not be a problem at all. All running threads at end of each test case are automatically stopped (and singletons are destroyed). But it was only possible to implement that because we have full control over the framework.

the important thing is that the test is not marked as passed.

If you can, use C++20 std::jthread. It joins on destruction. Otherwise wrap std::thread in struct my_thread{std::thread m_t; and let  my_thread::~my_thread(){m_t.join()};};. Using this simple class, you don't need to look anymore.

If you are stubborn enough to use google death tests, you can write EXPECT_EXIT or ASSERT_EXIT on a compound statement that includes the call to exit(0);. Like this:
class BadThread {
public:
    void run() { std::cout << "run()\n"; }
    void die() { std::thread t([]() { std::cout << "die!\n"; } );
    }
};

TEST(MyDeathTest, xxx) {  // remember about death tests naming
    GTEST_FLAG_SET(death_test_style, "threadsafe");
    BadThread sut;
    EXPECT_EXIT(
        {
            sut.die();
            std::exit(0);
        },
        testing::ExitedWithCode(0), "");
    EXPECT_EXIT(
        {
            sut.run();
            std::exit(0);
        },
        testing::ExitedWithCode(0), "");
}

After first failed expectation your test (and other testcases) will continue, and then finish gracefully and report the failures. However, read the death tests documentation and be aware of all the caveats.

Thanks. Of course, this approach makes the test cases a bit hard to read, but I could probably write a macro to wrap my actual testing code in one of the above EXPECT_EXIT blocks. I expect this will fully solve my issue.
